# Working with C# lists

Tags: c#, class, list, compiler-errors

I'm trying to understand how does lists work in C# but I can't run my application because I get those messages:

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility:
>   property type 'ClaseLista.ListNode' is
>   less accessible than property
>   'ClaseLista.List.PrimerNodo'  C:\Documents
>   and
>   Settings\Usuario\Escritorio\Listas\ClaseLista\List.cs 19  25  ClaseLista
>
> ---
>
> Error 2   Inconsistent accessibility:
>   property type 'ClaseLista.ListNode' is
>   less accessible than property
>   'ClaseLista.List.UltimoNodo'  C:\Documents
>   and
>   Settings\Usuario\Escritorio\Listas\ClaseLista\List.cs 24  25  ClaseLista
>
> ---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using ClaseLista;

namespace Listas
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List Lista1 = new List();
            int opcion = 1;
            while (opcion > 0 && opcion < 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                Console.WriteLine("x Menú Principal (dos datos) x");
                Console.WriteLine("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                Console.WriteLine("x                            x");
                Console.WriteLine("x 1: Insertar Alumnos        x");
                Console.WriteLine("x 2: Imprimir Lista          x");
                Console.WriteLine("x 3: Salir                   x");
                Console.WriteLine("x                            x");
                Console.WriteLine("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                Console.Write("Ingrese opción: ");
                opcion = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (opcion)
                {
                    case 1: int numero; string nombre, codigo;
                        Console.Write("Ingrese número de elementos: ");
                        numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        for (int i = 1; i <= numero; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Datos del alumno " + i);
                            Console.Write("Ingrese Nombre: ");
                            nombre = (Console.ReadLine());
                            Console.Write("Ingrese Codigo: ");
                            codigo = (Console.ReadLine());
                            Lista1.InsertaInicio(nombre, codigo);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (Lista1.EsVacio())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Lista Vacia");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Lista1.Imprimir();
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClaseLista
{
    public class List
    {
        //Constructor
        private ListNode primerNodo;
        private ListNode ultimoNodo;
        public List()
        {
            primerNodo = null;
            ultimoNodo = null;
        }
        //Propiedades
        public ListNode PrimerNodo
        {
            get { return primerNodo; }
            set { primerNodo = value; }
        }
        public ListNode UltimoNodo
        {
            get { return ultimoNodo; }
            set { ultimoNodo = value; }
        }
        //insertar al inicio
        public void InsertaInicio(object nom, object cod)
        {
            if (EsVacio())
                primerNodo = ultimoNodo = new ListNode(nom, cod, null);
            else
            {
                primerNodo = new ListNode(nom, cod, primerNodo);
            }
        }
        //comprobar si es vacio
        public bool EsVacio()
        {
            return primerNodo == null;
        }
        //Imprimir
        public void Imprimir()
        {
            ListNode current = primerNodo;
            while (current != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("|" + current.Nombre + " " + current.Codigo);
                current = current.Siguiente;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClaseLista
{
    class ListNode
    {
        //Constructor
        private object nombre;
        private object codigo;
        private ListNode siguiente;
        public ListNode()
        {
            nombre = null;
            codigo = null;
            siguiente = null;
        }
        public ListNode(object nomb, object cod, ListNode sig)
        {
            nombre = nomb;
            codigo = cod;
            siguiente = sig;
        }
        //Propiedades
        public object Nombre
        {
            get { return nombre; }
            set { nombre = value; }
        }
        public object Codigo
        {
            get { return codigo; }
            set { codigo = value; }
        }
        public ListNode Siguiente
        {
            get { return siguiente; }
            set { siguiente = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

You need to make ListNode public as well...

```
public class ListNode
```

Answer (score 2):

it's simply an issue to do with the visibility of your `ListNode` class - which is declared as

```
class ListNode
```

(And therefore has `internal` visibility)

Whereas your `List` class is declared as

```
public class List
```

Because `List` then declares one or more public properties of type `ListNode`, `ListNode` must also be public:

```
public class ListNode
```

Will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `ListNode` class is internal, while your `List` class is public.  Code outside your .NET assembly can access the `List` class, but they can't use the `PrimerNodo` or `UltimoNodo` properties unless they can access the `ListNode` class too, so the compiler gives you that error.

If you want code outside of your assembly to be able to access `ListNode`, you can make it public.  Otherwise, you can change the access modifier of the `List` class to internal or change the access modifier of the properties that use `ListNode` to private or internal.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have `ListNode` defined as:

```
namespace ClaseLista
{
    class ListNode
    {
```

By default, the compiler gives this an `internal` accessibility.  To get rid of the error, change this to be public:

```
namespace ClaseLista
{
    public class ListNode
    {
```

This is required because you define part of your *public API* using the `ListNode` class:

```
// This can't be public unless "ListNode" is public as well!
public ListNode PrimerNodo
{
    get { return primerNodo; }
    set { primerNodo = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make ListNode public:

```
namespace ClaseLista
{
   public class ListNode
   {
      //Constructor
      private object nombre;
      ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Your properties of type `ListNode` in the class `ClaseLista` are `public` but the `ListNode` type itself is not public.  This creates mutually exclusive access control for the compiler.  (After all, a consuming client can't very well use a property without being able to use the type for that property.)

For those properties to be public, the `ListNode` class also needs to be public.