# Working with lists in C#

Tags: c#, class, list

Im working with the code on this page [Working with C# lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315544/working-with-c-lists) since 2 days, and I have a problem  when I try to change the code to add items to the list after the previous item (instead before the previous item) .

```
//ListNode constructor params: name, code, nextNode
//Insert element after the first element
        public void InsertelementAfterTheFirst(object name, object code)
        {
            if (IsEmpty())
                FirstNode = LastNode = new ListNode(name, code, null);
            else
            {
                FirstNode = new ListNode(name, code, FirstNode);
            }
        }
```

I know I can use the  "List<>" collection in C#, but my intention is to learn how does the lists works.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So how can I change the code to add items after the previous item?

Comment: Looks like you're using your own implementation of a list... so Could you show us the full code of this imlpementation? We need to know how are you internally deal with the collection. An array?

Comment: Ok, Now I see the implementation i was asking for are in the link you supplied. Thanks.

Comment: if this is not for learning, you might want to use LinkedList<T>, which is an implementation of generic linked list in .NET.  Despite the ranting, gjvdkamp is somewhat valid, you can use too like Reflector or ILSpy and look at how it is implemented, especially AddAfter(...) method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pseudo code...

```
if (firstNode is empty)
{
  //new list...
  firstNode = lastNode = new Node(name, code, null);
}
else
{
  var node = new Node(name, code, firstNode.nextNode);
  firstNode.nextNode = node;
}
```

Only thing is, this is only good for adding a node after the first Node.  A better method might be to specify in the InsertAfter method which node you want to attach the new node to.  Or if you are using an iterator-like pattern (your Linked List class has Current node), you can do similar thing.. just get the current node and the code in the else branch above should still work (but instead firstNode, it will be currentNode).

Something like:

```
public ListNode InsertAfterCurrent(object name, object code)
{
  if (currentNode == null)
  {
    //assume new list
    currentNode = firstNode = lastNode = new ListNode(name, code, null);
  }
  else
  {
    currentNode.NextNode = new ListNode(name, code, currentNode.NextNode);
  }
}

public ListNode InsertAfter(ListNode anchor, object name, object code)
{
  if (anchor != null  && NodeIsPartOfList(anchor))
  {
    anchor.NextNode = new ListNode(name, code, anchor.NextNode);
  }
}

public bool NodeIsPartOfList(ListNode node)
{
  var current = firstNode;
  while (current != null)
  {
    if (current == node)
      return true;

    current = current.NextNode;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Before I answer this I feel I should mention that posting code in Spanish on an English speaking forum is in bad taste. I spent more time trying to understand your basically gibberish naming than writing this post.

Also, `List<>`, despite its poor naming, isn't implemented as a list. It's a wrapper over an array, which is why `.ToArray()` is so efficient.

Now to your specific problem, you want to set your head link to the node you just created, and set its next link to the previous head link:

```
if (EsVacio())
  primerNodo = ultimoNodo = new ListNode(nom, cod, null);
else
{
  var node=new ListNode(nom, cod, primerNodo);
  node.Siguiente=primerNodo;
  primerNodo=node;
}
```